# Moment.js only able to use it once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, momentjs

Earlier today I got help with getting moment.js working and it is working as it should except it can only be used once, or rather only displayed on one location and in one instance.

The code works but I want to be able to use it multiple times with different date each time.

I want it to work as below(Doesn't need to be div)

```
<body>
    <div id="inputDiv" style="display: none">2015-02-14 19:07:00</div>
     <!-- This is the date which will be "converted" and displayed in   #displayMoment -->
    <div id="displayMoment"> <!-- 4 day ago --> </div> 

    <div id="inputDiv" style="display: none">2015-02-15 19:07:00</div>
    <div id="displayMoment">  <!-- 3 days ago --></div>

    <div id="inputDiv" style="display: none">2015-02-18 19:07:00</div>
        <div id="displayMoment"> <!-- 2 hours ago --></div>

</body>
```

I tried getting the script to add '1' to the `#displayMoment` in order to be able to use `#displayMoment1`, `#displayMoment2` and so on... but it didn't work :/
The code works but I can only use `#displayMoment` once,

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9dgv1tmj/1/) that I got from someone earlier today

```
<div id="inputDiv">2015-02-18 19:07:00</div>
<div id="displayMoment"></div>

// use Moment.js to display current date in a div (#displayMoment)
var inputDiv = document.getElementById('inputDiv');
var eDisplayMoment = document.getElementById('displayMoment');
eDisplayMoment.innerHTML =  moment(inputDiv.innerHTML, "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss").fromNow();
```

I searched for it but I didn't know which 'keywords' to search for :(

Thanks in advance for your time

Comment: I want to make sure, you got multiple elements on your page with inputDiv the same id and that you're populating your element by using getElementById()? Not by getElementsById()?

Comment: embarrassingly I dont understand what that means, I'm not very good with javascript :( The code on my page is as I show it on the <body> example </body> EDIT: After reading it several times I got it, no, I don't know how to populate it by getElementById().  I tried adding several ids to document.getElementbyId('displayMoment', 'displayMoment2'); but that's as far as my brain could take me

Comment: Okay, give me a second I will rig a fiddle for you and explain how it works.

Comment: There's no such thing as `getElementsById` AFAIK, instead, make inputDiv a class and use `getElementsByClassName` and loop through the result.  The same goes for displayMoment, which can be found with `.children[0]`.

Comment: ^ mhm. I just made a mess up with what I said, that why I was gonna jfiddle for him.

Comment: Ah, it's cool, good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML File:

```
<div class="inputDiv">2014-12-20</div>
<div class="displayMoment"></div>
<div class="inputDiv">2015-01-20</div>
<div class="displayMoment"></div>
```

JS File:

```
// use Moment.js to display current date in a div (.displayMoment)
var inputDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('inputDiv');
var eDisplayMoment = document.getElementsByClassName('displayMoment');
for(i=0;i<=inputDiv.length;i++) {
    eDisplayMoment[i].innerHTML =  moment(inputDiv[i].innerHTML, "YYYY-MM-DD").fromNow();
}
```

What I did was establish an array by populating it with class name as you can see by getElementsByClassName(). Then I told it get the innerHtml check it return a date then put it back in the proper spot I took it from by using the array inputDiv[].

Comment: Exactly what I was asking for and it's easy to understand, thanks a bunch, this made me 5 years younger! I've been struggling with moment.js and giving up several times, finally it's working as it should and I can't stop smiling haha. Thanks a bunch, really appreciated!

Comment: Welcome. Go out and have a blast now! :P

Comment: LOL I definitely will! :P

Comment: Yep, also don't be scared to drop more questions down, tons of people are glad to help.